# Win7: Will doing "Run as administrator" on a .BAT file allow regsvr32 enough privlieges to register a DLL or OCX?

Tags: windows-7, dll

Will doing "Run as administrator" on a `.BAT` file allow `regsvr32` enough privlieges to register a `DLL` or `OCX`?

The .bat file contains:

```
regsvr32 -u SomeOCX.ocx
regsvr32 SomeOCX.ocx
```

Or, does the logged in user need to be an administrator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be issues with running `.bat` files by right-clicking and choosing *Run as Administrator*.  Another option is to start an elevated command prompt and execute the `.bat` file from there.

Answer (score 1):

if you not administrator then you cannot do "Run as administrator" (but you allways can use "RunAs")

and ofcouse  "Run as administrator" gives you all necessary rights to do "regsvr32"

Answer (score 0):

run as administrator should allow it to register as long as it is setup by a domain administrator.

Did you tested it ?

Comment: What needs to be setup by a domain administrator?